# Is it possible to change css color of struts2-jquery-grid-tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html, struts2

how can i change css style for my struts2-jquery-grid-tags 
I can't even change my header layer font size. Can any one tell, how can i change my grid style, color and other formats as like normal html element.

Comment: Is there any problem to change the css?

Comment: I am using the default struts2-jquery-grid.so the grid is by default blue in color. I did not know the css source for the default struts2-jquery-grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sj" uri="/struts-jquery-tags"%>
...
<sj:head jqueryui="true" 
         jquerytheme="customTheme" 
         customBasepath="relative/path/customThemesFolder"/>
```

and in your **customThemesFolder** create your [themeroller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/) custom theme (should be in *customTheme*). This should change your grid theme and you can change all the styles you want.

Hope this helps.

**EDITED**
When you download you get something like this:

```
/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom/css/THEME
```

and inside css, images etc. **THEME** is what you need. Be carefull - the css import in the page  or what you have must follow the previous jqgrid style.
The people say that if doesn't work, put this at the end of the page:

```
<script>
    $.subscribe('loadCustomCss', function(event,data){            
        $.struts2-jquery.requireCss(cssFile, basePath); 
    });
</script>
```

and in the grid tag (sj:head) add

```
onCompleteTopics="loadCustomCss"
```

If it's still not working try this script (not the previous):

```
<script>
    $.subscribe('loadCustomCss', function(event,data){
         $('head').append( $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').attr('href', '../customThemeFolder/myTheme.css') );
    });
</script>
```

Take care of the relative path.

Comment: I include this lines and I have included the jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css in the customBasePath.But it is not working.I copy only this file jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.css from themeroller.Is it necessary to copy and paste all files of theme roller into our project(webContent)

Answer (score 0):

The css of the grid is dynamically loaded from struts-jquery-grid-plugin.jar.

```
template/themes/ui.jqgride.css.
```

Open this file and you will find the the css keys which you can over ride.

On the other hand if you want to NOT update and add your jqgride css, you can dynamically remove the css from grid.

Here is a code which removes some of the defaults

```
$.subscribe('grid_compelete', function(event, data) {

       //remove mouse over color change
       $($("#gridtable")[0].grid.hDiv).find(".ui-jqgrid-labels th.ui-th-column").unbind("mouseenter").unbind("mouseleave");        

       //Change header color
       $($("#gridtable")[0].grid.hDiv).find(".ui-jqgrid-labels th.ui-th-column").addClass("yourClassColor");

    //remove the 'ui-' from the css classes which automaticly created by grid tag
    //the gbox_gridtable is the most top element in the grid
    $('#gbox_gridtable').find('*').andSelf().attr('class',
            function(i, css){
                if (typeof css !== 'undefined') {
                        return css.replace(/\ui-\S+/g, '');
                    }
           });


        // remove default td title in jquery grid
        $("td").each(function() {
            var td = $(this);
            if (td.attr("role") == "gridcell") {
                td.removeAttr("title");
            };
        });
 });
```

In the jsp:

```
<sjg:grid id="gridtable" onGridCompleteTopics="grid_compelete"
```